# WPF InputScope not working on Dialoghost .NET 6

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-6.0, inputscope

I have a dialogHost with a textbox, I need the inputscope to be numeric since the TouchKeyboard is used, in the user control it works fine but in the dialog the keyboard layout does not change.

```
   <materialDesign:DialogHost x:Name="dgh_addProduct" CloseOnClickAway="True" IsOpen="{Binding AddProduct}" Grid.RowSpan="4" >
            <materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
                <StackPanel Background="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignPaper}">
                    <TextBox  materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Cantidad" BorderThickness="2"
                                BorderBrush="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignDivider}"
                            Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignOutlinedTextBox}" Width="200" Margin="16"
                            PreviewTextInput="TextBoxNumeric_PreviewTextInput" InputScope="Number" />
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="16">
                        <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatDarkBgButton}"
                                Background="Red" BorderBrush="Transparent" Content="Close" Width="100"
                                Command="{Binding CloseAddProductCommand}"  Margin=" 8 0 16 0"/>
                        <Button  Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatAccentBgButton}"
                                BorderBrush="Transparent" Content="Agregar" Width="100"
                                Command="{Binding CloseAddProductCommand}" Margin=" 16 0 8 0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                   
                </StackPanel>
            </materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>


        </materialDesign:DialogHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution add the Embedded style to the dialog host, like this:

```
<materialDesign:DialogHost x:Name="dgh_addProduct" CloseOnClickAway="True" IsOpen="{Binding AddProduct}"
                Grid.RowSpan="4" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignEmbeddedDialogHost}">
            <materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
                <StackPanel Background="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignPaper}">
                    <TextBox  materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Cantidad" BorderThickness="2"
                                BorderBrush="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignDivider}"
                            Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignOutlinedTextBox}" Width="200" Margin="16"
                            PreviewTextInput="TextBoxNumeric_PreviewTextInput" InputScope="Number" />
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="16">
                        <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatDarkBgButton}"
                                Background="Red" BorderBrush="Transparent" Content="Close" Width="100"
                                Command="{Binding CloseAddProductCommand}"  Margin=" 8 0 16 0"/>
                        <Button  Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatAccentBgButton}"
                                BorderBrush="Transparent" Content="Agregar" Width="100"
                                Command="{Binding CloseAddProductCommand}" Margin=" 16 0 8 0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                   
                </StackPanel>
            </materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>


        </materialDesign:DialogHost>
```

Now it recognizes the input scope and change the touchkeyboard layout.